# Floating bubble windows like MKannotation or MAattachedWindow but without using mapview for iOS7

Tags: ios, xcode5

I have a background image in an iOS7 application, and when the user taps specific locations of the image, it is supposed to display a bubble window with some information about that location. I mean something similar to MKAnnotation view callout but without using any map.
I hope you can help me to design such a page.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create UIButtons for the annotations, and a custom view for the bubble.

This should help
https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController